# How can I get the first word in a string and have it work also for the case when the string has just one word

Tags: c#, string

I am using this code to get the first word in a `string`:

```
var currentVersionNumber = 
   currentVersion
      .Substring(0, currentVersion.IndexOf(" ", System.StringComparison.Ordinal));
```

But there is a problem if there is *only one word* in a `string`.  Does anyone have any suggestion as to how I could handle this case also?

Comment: just check what `currentVersion.IndexOf(...)` returns ... if it's -1 then return full string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd go with:

```
   var currentVersionNumber = currentVersion.Split(' ').FirstOrDefault();
```

`Split` will return an array of words, and `FirstOrDefault` will get you first one if the array is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

If *word* means any combination of *whitespace charactes*, you can try regular expressions:

```
var currentVersionNumber = Regex.Match(currentVersion, @"\S+").Value;
```

If version is expected to be a *number* (e.g. we want `"1234567"` from, say, `"ver:1234567 78 93 223"`):

```
var currentVersionNumber = Regex.Match(currentVersion, @"[0-9]+").Value;
```